# How can I set random to change at each loop in python

Tags: python, random

I want to create a loop that generates a different equation for each loop. But when I tried to create a code, it only created the same equations several times.

```
import random
count=range(random.randint(1,10))
terms_range=range(1,11)
num_terms=random.radint(1,10)

#This is where the calculation will be written
calculation=''
result_from_user=''
signs=''

def sign_generator(x):
  #This function will randomly generate the sign
  sign=random.randint(1,4)
  if sign == 1:
     x = '+'
     return x
  elif sign == 2:
     x = '-'
     return x
  elif sign == 3:
     x= '*'
     return x
  else:
     x='/'
     return x

    

for x in count:
  while num_terms>0:
     terms=random.randint(1,9)
     terms=str(terms)
     signs=sign_generator(signs)
     if num_terms !=1:
         calculation=calculation+terms+signs
     else:
         calculation=calculation+terms
     num_terms-=1
        
  print(calculation)
  result_from_user=input('= ')
```

How should I fix my code?

Comment: There's a typo in this code.  Have you tried actually running it?

Comment: The code works for me, generates new and random equations. (Also fix that type in line 4)

Comment: I have run this code several times but got the same equations for each loop. And thanks for pointing out the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the same result over and over because you only build one `calculation` and then exhaust `num_terms`.  To fix this you'd need to reset `calculation` and `num_terms` in each loop:

```
for x in count:
    calculation = ""
    num_terms = random.randint(1, 10)
    while num_terms > 0:
        terms = random.randint(1, 9)
        terms = str(terms)
        signs = sign_generator(signs)
        if num_terms != 1:
            calculation = calculation+terms+signs
        else:
            calculation = calculation+terms
        num_terms -= 1

    print(calculation)
```

prints:

```
7+5-3/5-3
7+4*4
9/4/2
3-8/7-1*4*5-3*5/1
8*9-8
1/1*3+5+3/7
6-9+7-2*7-6
4/7*3-3*9/7*6-3
8*7/8*1+7/2*9/9/6
```

Going further, the overall code can be simplified quite a bit by using `random.choice` to generate the `sign` and iterating over a `range` to build the terms instead of using a `while` loop.  That gives you way fewer variables to keep track of and makes the whole thing only seven lines of code:

```
import random


for _ in range(random.randint(1, 10)):
    calculation = ""
    for _ in range(random.randint(0, 9)):
        calculation += str(random.randint(1, 9))
        calculation += random.choice("+-*/")
    calculation += str(random.randint(1, 9))

    print(calculation)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work when I try, just fixed misspelling in line 5:

```
num_terms=random.radint(1,10)
```

to

```
num_terms=random.randint(1,10)
```